# Highcharts: Conditional tooltip based on multiple series names (OR logic operator)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

It is usual to be able to adjust the tooltip format based on the the name of the series in highchart, using the following type of code:

```
tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return ''+
                        this.x +': '+ this.y +
                        (this.series.name == 'Recovered' ? '%' : '');
                    }
          }
```

The above says in the last line, if this series name is 'Recovered' then add '%' else don't add anything.

However I want two of my series to have % not just one, so I want to add an OR operator in, something like

```
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return ''+
                this.x +': '+ this.y +
                (this.series.name == 'Recovered'||'Targeted' ? '%' : '');
        }
    }
```

So that both those series have the % added. But the above method does not work for me. Any ideas? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have discovered how to do this - leaving question up in case it helps anyone else. The correct syntax for this is:

```js
tooltip: {
  formatter: function() {
    return ''+
           this.x +': '+ this.y +
           (this.series.name == 'Recovered(%)'||this.series.name =='Defaulted(%)' ? '%' : '');
  }
}
```